# FileSystem.copyAsync not working in expo(React Native)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, filesystems

I have a code that picks an image and copy the content from that URI into the application's FileSystem.documentDirectory in order to keep it persistent. but it throw a ***"[Error: Argument of an incompatible class: class java.lang.String cannot be passed as an argument to
parameter expecting interface java.util.Map.]"*** error

My Code:

```js
const fileName = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "myfiles/targetImage." + extention;
await FileSystem.copyAsync(nTarget.image, fileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass options parameter {}
[RelocatingOptions in expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#relocatingoptions)

```
const copyImage = async () => {
              await FileSystem.copyAsync({
                from: oldPath,
                to: newPath,
              });
            };
```